# Sum and subtract with GROUP BY in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to display the remaining quantity in a supply.

I have two tables:

**`supply_inventory_list` table:**

```
supply_id  quantity  unit    item_name         supply_description       date_received        
---------  --------  ------  ----------------  -----------------------  -------------
        1         5  REAM    LEGAL BOND PAPER  CANON LEGAL BOND PAPER   2019-08-27
        2         5  REAM    A4 BOND PAPER     PAPER ONE A4 BOND PAPER  2019-08-27
        3         5  REAM    LEGAL BOND PAPER  HP LEGAL BOND PAPER      2019-08-30
```

**`supply_employee_list` table:**

```
emp_supply_id  supply_id  deployed_quantity  employee_name            date_deployed        
-------------  ---------  -----------------  -----------------------  --------------------
            1          3                  2  ALEX WARD                2019-08-29 16:00:00  
            2          3                  1  EDWARD COLLINS           2019-08-29 16:00:00
```

This is the query I tried, but I am not getting the result that i want:

```
SELECT 
    supply_inventory_list.supply_id,
    quantity,
    quantity - IFNULL(deployed_quantity, 0) AS 'AVAILABLE QUANTITY',
    unit,
    item_name,
    supply_description,
    date_received,
    IFNULL(deployed_quantity, 0) AS 'deployed_quantity'
FROM supply_inventory_list 
LEFT JOIN supply_employee_list 
    ON supply_employee_list.`supply_id` = supply_inventory_list.`supply_id` 
WHERE item_name = 'LEGAL BOND PAPER'
ORDER BY date_received DESC
```

This is the result I'm getting:

```
supply_id  quantity  AVAILABLE QUANTITY  unit    item_name         supply_description      date_received  deployed_quantity  
---------  --------  ------------------  ------  ----------------  ----------------------  -------------  -------------------
        3         5                   3  REAM    LEGAL BOND PAPER  HP LEGAL BOND PAPER     2019-08-30                       2
        3         5                   4  REAM    LEGAL BOND PAPER  HP LEGAL BOND PAPER     2019-08-30                       1
        1         5                   5  REAM    LEGAL BOND PAPER  CANON LEGAL BOND PAPER  2019-08-27                       0
```

This is not the result I'm looking for. I the `quantity` to be deducted based on `deployed_quantity`. This is the result I'm looking for:

```
supply_id  quantity  AVAILABLE QUANTITY  unit    item_name         supply_description      date_received  deployed_quantity  
---------  --------  ------------------  ------  ----------------  ----------------------  -------------  -------------------
        3         5                   2  REAM    LEGAL BOND PAPER  HP LEGAL BOND PAPER     2019-08-30                       3
        1         5                   5  REAM    LEGAL BOND PAPER  CANON LEGAL BOND PAPER  2019-08-27                       0
```

As you can see the `AVAILABLE QUANTITY` is 2 and the `deployed_quantity` is 3 because the first employee deployed 2 quantities and the second one deployed 1.

How do I produce this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to find the sum of deployed quantity then subtract that from inventory quantity -

```
SELECT SIL.supply_id,
       SIL.quantity,
       SIL.quantity - IFNULL(SEL.deployed_quantity, 0) AS 'AVAILABLE QUANTITY',
       SIL.unit,
       SIL.item_name,
       SIL.supply_description,
       SIL.date_received,
       IFNULL(SEL.deployed_quantity, 0) AS 'deployed_quantity'
FROM supply_inventory_list SIL
LEFT JOIN (SELECT supply_id, SUM(deployed_quantity) deployed_quantity
           FROM supply_employee_list
          GROUP BY supply_id) SEL
ON SEL.`supply_id` = SIL.`supply_id` 
WHERE SIL.item_name = 'LEGAL BOND PAPER'
ORDER BY SIL.date_received DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the aggregated result for `supply_employee_list`: `sum(deployed_quantity) group by supply_id` instead of the individual rows `from supply_employee_list`:

```
SELECT 
    i.supply_id,
    i.quantity,
    i.quantity - IFNULL(e.deployed_quantity, 0) AS 'AVAILABLE QUANTITY',
    i.unit,
    i.item_name,
    i.supply_description,
    i.date_received,
    IFNULL(e.deployed_quantity, 0) AS 'deployed_quantity'
FROM supply_inventory_list i
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT supply_id, SUM(deployed_quantity) deployed_quantity
    FROM supply_employee_list
    GROUP BY supply_id
) e ON e.supply_id = i.supply_id`
WHERE i.item_name = 'LEGAL BOND PAPER'
ORDER BY date_received DESC;
```